# Iteritems on a slice of a list

Tags: python, list, iteration, subclass, slice

`iteritems` on a `dict` can useful.

Occasionally `iteritems` is useful for a slice of a list and can be (crudely) implemented as follows:

```
import itertools

class List(list):
  def iteritems(self, slice=None):
    if slice is None: return enumerate(self)
    else: return itertools.izip(range(slice.start,slice.stop,slice.step), self[slice])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  l=List("hAnGtEn")
  print l
  print list(l.iteritems())
  print list(l.iteritems(slice(1,7,2)))
```

Output:

```
['h', 'A', 'n', 'G', 't', 'E', 'n']
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'A'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'G'), (4, 't'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'n')]
[(1, 'A'), (3, 'G'), (5, 'E')]
```

Is there a more "pythonic" list slicing syntax that should be used?

p.s.

```
range(slice.start,slice.stop,slice.step)
```

does not handle certain special cases very well: e.g. where `stop=-1`, `start=None` or `step=None`. How can the example range/slice implementation be also improved?

Comment: Discussion of improvements to working code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Note: reposted to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70959/iteritems-on-a-slice-of-a-python-list

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iterools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for this:

> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If start is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until start is reached. Afterward, elements are returned consecutively unless step is set higher than one which results in items being skipped. If stop is None, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all; otherwise, it stops at the specified position.

However, the docs also note that it does not support negative values for start, stop or step.